# security in browser

Tags: security, browser

is it safe to store the user's userid in a cookie.why?

Answer (score 2):

Depends entirely on what the id is being used for.

If it is for authentication, it is a bad idea. I could change it to anything.

You are better off storing a nonce that is renewed every so often (every page if it won't crush your server). Then match this in your database to the authenticated user.

Answer (score 1):

It's alright, just make sure you are performing validation on that cookie.

Answer (score 1):

If it is for any sort of session management, or is used as a key to gain access to sensitive information (password, financial, medical etc) then you don't want to store it in a cookie - certainly not in the clear anyway.

Good practice is to use a session cookie which is encrypted to make it hard to guess, validated against an internal server reference, frequently renewed (on any change in security status - eg going from http to https pages) and revoked on leaving or logging out to prevent reuse.

Answer (score -1):

It is ok to do that. But before committing anything important, ask that user's password for verification.